# Count total records in File and compare with trailer records in Perl

Tags: perl

I have the following code

```perl
if ( -e $filein ) {

    if ( open( FILEIN, $filein ) ) {

        print log_date() . "STARTING TO CHECK  FILE \n";

        while ( <FILEIN> ) {

            chomp( $_ );

            if ( length( $_ ) == $l_recordLength ) {

                $rectype = substr( $_, $0, 3 );
                my $config = "fdposmarkertaxentity.ini";

                if ( -e $config ) {

                    my $cfg = new Config::IniFiles( -file => $config );
                    print "$rectype \n";

                    if ( $rectype eq "999" ) {

                        print log_date() . "CHECK TRAILER RECORD IN CHECKFILE SUBROUTINE WHILE CHECKING  FILE \n";
                        $filereccnt = substr( $_, 3, 17 );

                        if ( ( $filereccnt != $. ) || ( $. <= 2 ) ) {

                            if ( $BLog ) {

                                $errhdrordtlrec += $l_valueOne;

                                print HEADERTRAILER_ERROR_LOGFILE log_date() . "$. \n";
                                print HEADERTRAILER_ERROR_LOGFILE log_date() . "$_ \n";
                                print HEADERTRAILER_ERROR_LOGFILE log_date() . "====================================================================================================== \n";
                                $ERRHDRTRLRRCRDMSG = "Trailer record count does not match record or no records present in file.";
                                print HEADERTRAILER_ERROR_LOGFILE log_date() . "$ERRHDRTRLRRCRDMSG $filereccnt \n";
                                print HEADERTRAILER_ERROR_LOGFILE log_date() . "====================================================================================================== \n";

                                $BTrailerRecAlreadyRead = $l_valueOne;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my record file contains below inputs

```
000FDPOSTAXENTITY2018021317243200001
DTL11~|~|110~|~|220~|~|T0333~|~|~|~|
DTL11~|~|333~|~|444~|~|T0555~|~|~|~|
DTL11~|~|555~|~|222~|~|T0777~|~|~|~|
99900000000000000005~|~|~|~|~|~|~|~|
```

I want to compare the number of lines from an input file. `00000000000000005` is the line count in a file. My record file has five lines. If the detail record is 5 and the trailer record  `00000000000000005` is not 5 or something like `00000000000000007` then it will throw error message like

> Trailer record count doesnot match

else if it is `00000000000000005` it will throw

> Trailer record count matches

Can anyone help me out with the solution?

Comment: There's no need to do those `-e` checks. You *must* test that the return code from `return` is non zero and print the value of `$!` to give the reason for failure. Alternatively you can enable `use autodie` which will do all the necessary checks implicitly.

Comment: *"If the detail record is 5 and the trailer record  `00000000000000005` is not 5 or something like `00000000000000007`"* That's a bizarre requirement. Okay, you tell me: is `00000000000000005` "something like" `00000000000000007`?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly. This is how I would write it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $records = 0;
my $line;
while (<DATA>) {
    #print "LINE: $_";

    # inside a record
    if (/^000/.../^999/) {
        #print "RECORD: $_";

        # start of record
        $line = 0 if /^000/;

        $line++;

        # end of record
        if (/^999/) {
            $records++;

            # record length check
            my($record_length) = /^999(\d+)/;
            $record_length += 0; # integer
            die "Record $records is $line line(s) long, but should be $record_length!\n"
                unless $line == $record_length;

            print "Record $records is OK\n";
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
asdjaslkdjasd
asdjasdjasld
asdjasdaskd

000FDPOSTAXENTITY2018021317243200001
DTL11~|~|110~|~|220~|~|T0333~|~|~|~|
DTL11~|~|333~|~|444~|~|T0555~|~|~|~|
DTL11~|~|555~|~|222~|~|T0777~|~|~|~|
99900000000000000005~|~|~|~|~|~|~|~|

asdasdasd

asdasdasdasd

000FDPOSTAXENTITY2018021317243200001
DTL11~|~|110~|~|220~|~|T0333~|~|~|~|
DTL11~|~|555~|~|222~|~|T0777~|~|~|~|
99900000000000000005~|~|~|~|~|~|~|~|

asdasdasd
```

Example run on the embedded data:

```
Record 1 is OK
Record 2 is 4 line(s) long, but should be 5!
```

Comment: Hi i would like to compare the no of columns from the file with "00000000000000005" ie the trailer record. Lets say i am counting the no of lines from an input file with $. and it says it is 5 and i want to compare the trailer record ie "00000000000000005" if it is "00000000000000006" then it will say trailer record count doesnot match

Comment: I don't quite understand that you insist on a string "00000000000000006" and can't use an integer. If you need another check then add `die "...." unless $line == $l_recordLength` where `$l_recordLength` is an input parameter.

Comment: can you please tell what these line $line = 0 if /^000/;

        $line++; is actually doing?

Comment: If the current line, i.e. `$_`, starts with the string `000` then set `$line` to 0. `$line++` increments the value. So at the beginning of the record `$line` will be 1 and incremented for every following line.

Comment: ...and `while(<DATA>)` just loops over the lines after `__DATA__` and assigns each line to `$_`. But that loop and the data is just there so that the code that really matters, i.e. what is inside the `while` loop, can be tested by running the script.

Comment: thank you so much and what does the below means       
  my($record_length) = /^999(\d+)/;
            $record_length += 0; # integer

Comment: The first line extracts the number string after `999` from the start of the line and assigns it to `$record_length`. The following `+= 0` coerces the string to an integer, because "number in string" + "number" equals a "number".

Comment: just one more question. How can i redirect the output to the log file in the same code?

Comment: `open(my $logfh, ">", "logfile.txt");
print $logfh "message to log...\n";`

All of the above is basic Perl stuff. I would suggest to take a Perl beginners tutorial.